# On changing device's time and date to an older time, the local authentication gives a system cancel error

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, localauthentication

I'm using local authentication in my app but I've observed this strange behavior in my app when I change the device's time and date in the settings app and return to my app and press this button, the `LAContext()` gives me an error

> Misbehaving caller PID:10565 has made too many authentication
>   requests.

The error code is -4 and it is a system cancel error. I don't know why I get this error.

```
@IBAction func touchIdAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        print("hello there!.. You have clicked the touch ID")

        let myContext = LAContext()
        let myLocalizedReasonString = "Biometric Authntication testing !! "

        var authError: NSError?
        if #available(iOS 8.0, macOS 10.12.1, *) {
            if myContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authError) {
                myContext.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: myLocalizedReasonString) { success, evaluateError in

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if success {
                            // User authenticated successfully, take appropriate action
                            self.successLabel.text = "Awesome!!... User authenticated successfully"
                        } else {
                            // User did not authenticate successfully, look at error and take appropriate action
                            self.successLabel.text = "Sorry!!... User did not authenticate successfully"
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Could not evaluate policy; look at authError and present an appropriate message to user
                successLabel.text = "Sorry!!.. Could not evaluate policy."
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions

            successLabel.text = "Ooops!!.. This feature is not supported."
        }
    }
```

Comment: “when I change the device's time and date in the settings app” Why would you do that?

Comment: Its a use case for quality assurance testing.

Comment: Well clearly it confuses the system.

Comment: Well, now you can be assured that the system will reject attempts to manipulate time :). I am not surprised that the system detects issues when time goes backward - particularly functions related to security & cryptography.  You probably need to restart the device after changing the time backwards.

Comment: Yeah, it's a likely possibility.